# Putting tilde below letters in R Markdown

Tags: r-markdown, notation, mathematical-expressions

I am trying to put a '~', without the quotes, under a letter, to specify a vector. I googled and found all the other diacritics you can put around the letters/numbers for R Markdown, but nothing for '~' below them.
Any directions would be appreciated.

Comment: What type of output are you working with?

Comment: I'm knitting the markdown to an html.